Typesetting \mathbb in tufte-latex
I am unable to typeset (for example) $\mathbb{N}$ correctly while using tufte-latex classes. It appears as "IN" instead of the proper symbol. The same happens for other \mathbb letters.
My understanding is that this is a known issue. Has anyone solved it? I have been around the block several times with chatGPT now, to no avail.
I am using the code available at https://github.com/Tufte-LaTeX/tufte-latex
Here is a sample with tufte-latex and without tufte-latex
The N is particularly bad.
Note that I have tried many other iterations of font definitions, including changing font definitions inside the tufte .cls and .def files. Nothing seems to work.

Welcome to TeX.SE, please provide your MWE for better understanding

These shapes are from PazoMath fonts and they are used in tufte style. This is decision of the designer of this style. Try texdoc pazotest. If you want something different, you can design your own style, of course.

The tufte-book class loads mathpazo (which is really old and unmaintained), which in turn allows to disable those blackboard bold characters. You can pass the relevant option as a global one and then set the blackboard bold font yourself; here I use the AMS one.
\documentclass[noBBpl]{tufte-book}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbb}{U}{msb}{m}{n}

\begin{document}

Here's $\mathbb{N}$.

$\mathbb{A}\mathbb{C}\mathbb{R}$

\end{document}


A different strategy is to use NewPX instead of mathpazo:
\documentclass[nofonts]{tufte-book}
\usepackage{newpx}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

Here's $\mathbb{N}$.

$\mathbb{A}\mathbb{C}\mathbb{R}$

\end{document}



Why loading amsmath? (in first example at least; edit: and in second two)

@user691586 Any document using \mathbb is about “serious” mathematics, so amsmath is essentially mandatory.

ok, I don't disagree.

Actually there is no need to load amsmath explicitly, as newpxmath does that anyway.

@campa Maybe newpx, but not every math font package

Thank you @egreg!
Here's a summary of what I've learned (mainly from you) for the people of the future:
\documentclass[nofonts]{tufte-book}

will remove all of the font presets. Then you can declare your own fonts just as you would if you weren't using tufte-latex. (Here are two examples):
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}


or
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}

